# How to crawl the whole website and scrape data of every web page in python 3 with scrappy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

I am trying to crawl a website and scrape some data from each web page in python 3 using scrapy. i have already scraped data for one singe page by providing it's url but now i want to scrape data for every page.i think i am missing something because my code just not crawling because it's unable to extract the data. i have tried below code but no success.
i am stuck here so kindly help me
i am using anaconda3 with pycharm compiler

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "quotes"
allowed_domains = ['meishij.net']
start_urls = [
    'https://www.meishij.net/'
    #'https://www.meishij.net/zuofa/huaguluobodunpaigutang.html'

]
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
)

def parse(self, response):
    title = response.xpath('//*[(@id = "tongji_title")]/text()').extract_first()
    print(title)
    tags = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "yj_tags", " " ))]//a/text()').extract()
    print("Tags: ")
    print(tags)

    recipeDetails = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "small", " " ))]//text()').extract()
    author = response.xpath('//*[(@id = "tongji_author")]//text()').extract()
    print("Recipee Details and Author name: ")
    print(recipeDetails,author)
    description = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "materials", " " ))]//p/text()').extract()
    print("Recipee Description: ")
    print(description)
    steps = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "content", " " ))]//p[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]//text()').extract()
    print("Recipee Steps: ")
    print(steps)

    #tips = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "cpc_h2", " " ))]//p/text()').extract_first()
    tips= response.css('.cpc_h2+p::text').extract()
    print("Recipee Tips")
    print(tips)
    comments = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "p1", " " ))]//text()').extract()
    print("Comments")
    print(comments)

 process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @AmiHollander i am not getting the data

Comment: @AmiHollander it just returns empty square brackets . i don't understand what's wrong with it

Comment: @AmiHollander i think it just calls the parse method for the first url

Comment: i have done it. actually i was not calling the parse method in the callback attribute. i have changed this line of code "  rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('zuofa')), callback='parse_web', follow=True),
    )" parse_web is the name of parsing definition

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. actually I was not calling the parse method in the callback attribute. I have changed this line of code

```
rules = ( 
   Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('zuofa')), callback='parse_web', follow=True)
)
```

`parse_web` is the name of parsing definition